# How to get column B value in python pandas based on column A list

Tags: python, pandas, list, series

[image]

df got 2 columns hands, and value, i want to get value based on hands, but alwasy get error."length must match to compare'.

This is my query: df[df.hands==['S2', 'S3', 'S4', 'S5', 'H7']].value

Expect outcome is 7.05432

Comment: what is the output of `print(type(df.loc[0,'hands']))`?

Comment: <class 'numpy.ndarray'>

Comment: Please show the DF as code to initialize it, not a picture. Also, please show a full traceback on a [mcve]

Comment: jesus, the question is short and ez to reproduce. you can use any example in column A, maybe just one row {[a,b] 1} , how to query out 1 based on [a,b]?

Comment: i tried this question for half an hour, tries series.apply or index with loc...but still did not manage to figure out a correct way...can get some expert on pandas to help....must be some understanding i missed on the object type...

Comment: ok, managed to find a way, but not elegant, just for sharing: for i in range(len(df)):
    if(df.loc[i,'hands']==['S2', 'S3', 'S4', 'S5', 'H7']).all():
        print(df.iloc[i].value)

Comment: There are various reasons why your queries might not work which are hidden in a Jupyter notebook display. Please provide a means to reconstruct the specific DF you have on our side.

Comment: always put code, data and full error message as text (not screenshot, not link) in question (not in comment).

Answer (score 0):

`pandas` was created to work rather single values in cell and when you compare it with list then it tries to compare every value from list with different `row` and this make problem.

You can use `apply` with own function to compare every row with full list.

Minimal working code which everyone can copy and test.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'hands': [
        ['S2', 'S3', 'S4', 'S5', 'H7'],
        ['S2', 'S3', 'S4', 'S5', 'C7'],
    ],
    'value': [7.05432, 3.1415],
})

find = ['S2', 'S3', 'S4', 'S5', 'H7']

def check(row):
    return (row == find)

mask = df.hands.apply(check)
df[ mask ].value
#df[ df.hands.apply(check) ].value
```

Or with `lambda`

```
find = ['S2', 'S3', 'S4', 'S5', 'H7']

mask = df.hands.apply(lambda row:(row == find))
df[ mask ].value
#df[ df.hands.apply(lambda row:(row == find)) ].value

#check = lambda row:(row == find)
#mask = df.hands.apply(check)
#df[ mask ].value
```

---

**EDIT:**

You didn't show data as code so I assumend that you have it as standard list but because my code gives error for your real data so I check something and it seems that you have `numpy.array` in `dataframe` and when numpy array compare  `[1,2] == [1,5]` then it gives list `[True, False]` instead single result `False` and it needs `all()` - `all([1,2] == [1,5])` to get single result.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'hands': [
        np.array(['S2', 'S3', 'S4', 'S5', 'H7']),
        np.array(['S2', 'S3', 'S4', 'S5', 'C7']),
    ],
    'value': [7.05432, 3.1415],
})

find = ['S2', 'S3', 'S4', 'S5', 'H7']
#find = np.array(['S2', 'S3', 'S4', 'S5', 'H7'])

def check(row):
    return all(row == find)

mask = df.hands.apply(check)
print( df[ mask ].value )

mask = df.hands.apply(lambda row:all(row == find))
print( df[ mask ].value )

#check = lambda row:all(row == find)
#mask = df.hands.apply(check)
#print( df[ mask ].value )
```

Comment: i did try the second method, but get this error unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray'

Comment: second method works form me - for data which I show in answer. You should show your data - maybe you different data or different type of data and this make problem. All this shows how important is to add all details in question (and why you are downvoted)

Comment: there can be also other problem - you have mistake in other place and it has nothing to do with my code - you didn't show FULL error message and I can confirm it. Adn this again shows how important is to add all details.

Comment: I seems you have `numpy.array` instead of standard list  and it needs `all()` to work correctly. See new code in answer.

Comment: thanks. this is what i am looking for df.hands.apply(lambda row:all(row == find)). and thanks for pointing out the difference on number.array and list, that indeed is the root cause